# numpy append() function doesn't change my ndarray?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to add something to a ndarray, what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
sequence =np.repeat(1, 4)
print(sequence)
np.append(sequence, 7)
print(sequence)
```

Expected result in console:
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 7]

Actual result:
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]

Comment: `sequence = np.append(sequence, 7)`

Comment: It doesn't do it in-place, so you have to access the return value of `np.append`

Comment: `np.append` is not a list append clone.  Do not use as such; better yet don't use it at all!  Also you can't add an element to just one row of a 2d array.  Again, arrays are not the same as nested lists.

Comment: It's not in-place! Of course! Thank you you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.append()` returns a new list, so what you wanna do is you wanna do `sequence = np.append(sequence, 7)`